# How to execute SQL query in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

How to use this query in ASP.NET MVC to copy data from table and send it to another table?

```
 INSERT INTO tblFee (AdmissionFee, Tuitionfee)
     SELECT AdmissionFee, TuitionFee 
     FROM tblFee
```

Comment: _another_ table?!? (You're inserting into the same table.)

Comment: No i will change it later just for testing inserting into same table but i dont have an idea how to write c# code in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a simple `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to execute this query.

Done properly, it would look something like this:

```
string connectionString = "......";  // typically, you get this from a config file
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblFee (AdmissionFee, Tuitionfee) SELECT AdmissionFee, TuitionFee FROM dbo.tblFee;";

// set up your connection and command, in "using" blocks
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(conn, query))
{
    // open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open();

    // since you are doing an "INSERT" - use "ExecuteNonQuery"
    // this returns only the number of rows inserted - no result set        
    int rowsInserted = cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
    conn.Close();
}
```

But with this, you're really just duplicating every row that's already in `dbo.tblFee` and re-inserting them back into the same table .... is that really what you're looking for??

Comment: Is there another way to adding Admissionfee,tuitionfee automatically in c# asp.net mvc by every month once i enter manually fees for student in tblfee